# Installing Firebase Error in React Native when i try to use in ios

Tags: firebase, react-native

I use react native, and setup firebase follow this: https://rnfirebase.io/.
When run terminal:

> cd ios
> pod install --repo-update

I got error like in picture: [image]

Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error and solved: Change to another wifi (new IP). lol